# C++ constructor initialization list alternative in C?

Tags: c++, c, constructor, initialization

In C++, classes constructors can use initialization lists, which I am told is a performance feature that improves by avoiding extra assignments. So I wonder if there is a similar approach to achieve the same benefits in C for functions that basically serve the same purpose to initialize structs as C++ class constructors?

I am a little unclear on how exactly the feature works in a C++ compiler, so any additional info on the subject will also be appreciated.

Comment: I'm dubious as to the claim that it's a performance feature.

Comment: You can make data static if you want to avoid unnecessary (repeated) initialising.

Comment: @Joe - IIRC that claim was made in a LiveLessons's "C++ fundamentals", but might be wrong, it was certainly made in some video tutorial I've been watching.

Comment: Worth to see some existing questions & answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%2b%2b%5d%5bconstructor%5d%20initialization%20list

Comment: @Joe - the reason for the claim that it's a performance improvement is that if you don't use an initializer list, all data members get default constructed. The time spent doing that is wasted if the constructor body assigns to the data members. It's not a strong argument, but so be it. The reason for using an initializer list is that it's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ constructors, initialization lists allow the C++ compiler to constructor members in-place, at the location of the member variable, instead of using an assignment operator, copy-constructor, or move-constructor to initialize the member variable.  See [Section 10.6 of the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html) for more details.

In C, there are no such automatic operations provided by the C compiler.  This means that the programmer controls all initialization directly, and no special-language features are required to avoid these extra operations.

To be a little more clear, consider what happens when you use assignment to initialize in a C++ constructor:

1. The member variable is first constructed with a default constructor
2. A temporary object is constructed
3. An assignment or move-assignment operator is called to re-initialize the member variable with the temporary.
4. Call the destructor on the temporary.

While some compilers can optimize this away in some situations, your mileage may vary, and no C++ compiler can optimize these steps away in all situations.  Now, consider how a programmer would exactly duplicate these steps in C:

```
void my_struct_init(struct my_struct* sp)
{
  member_init_default(&sp->the_member);  /* default constructor for member */

  struct member memb; /* temporary on stack */
  member_init_other(&memb, ...params...);  /* initialize memb */
  member_assign(&sp->the_member,&memb);    /* assign member */
  member_finalize(&memb);                  /* finalize the temporary */
}
```

Few C programmers would do this (without good reason).  Instead, they would automatically code the optimization:

```
  member_init_other(&sp->the_member, ...params...);
```

The feature exists in C++ because the compiler does a lot of automatic things for the programmer.  This is often makes life easier for the programmer, but requires features like initialization lists to help the compiler generate optimum code.  C compilers present a much simpler model of the underlying machine, do fewer things automatically, and thus require fewer features (though not necessarily less work) to generate similarly optimal code.

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't have any similar feature, however since C also doesn't have constructors, there is no danger of unnecessary assignments.

The bigger principle is that introducing one feature into a language often creates a need for additional features to reinforce the original.  An trivial example is threads. If threads are built into the language as a feature, then there is the immediate question of how to synchronize them.  Hence synchronization is also needed.  So you see languages (like C) with no built-in threads or synchronization and languages with both, but not one without the other.  Here, constructors is to threads as synchonization is to list initializers.

Comment: I am aware there is no such feature, I just ask if the performance advantages are applicable and can be implemented in C, like most of the C++ features that are absent like polymorphism for example...

Comment: In C variables are just space in memory until you assign to them. In C++ variables are constructed, with null values if appropriate, when they are declared. Initialisers allow you to make sure a null value is not assigned before you assign the value you want.

Comment: Yes @Will is right, and it's just what I said.  Constructors in C++ are where the danger of multiple assignments might possibly cause a problem. Since C has no constructors, there is no danger, so there is no need for any similar kind of initialization.  Assignment statements are all you have and all  you need.

Comment: @Will - the initialization is done by a **default constructor** which may or may not initialize with a null value. Note, also, that "null value" isn't very descriptive, and isn't commonly used.

Comment: Indeed. I wanted to try and explain the differences as simply as possible. I suppose the expression "default values" could be used instead. I just used null to mean the values were kind of unimportant, as they were about to be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in C. The closest thing is [designated initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can write a separate function and call it when you are creating an object from a class and then pass it to it:

C:

```
typedef struct {
        int x;
}mine;

void mine_initializer(mine* me)
{
        me->x = 4; //initialization
}

int main(void)
{
        mine me;
        mine_initializer(&me);
        return 0;
}
```

Also you can do that in C++:

```
struct mine{
        int x;
        void initialize()
        {
                x = 4; //initialization
        }
};



void main(void)
{
        mine me;
        me.initialize();
        printf("%d",me.x);
}
```

this will output `4` as the result.

Comment: Not really what I was asking for, plus you use the member access `.` on a pointer...

Comment: @ddriver Fixed it! oopsie! Do you want an automatic initializer?